# Check if Raven Db exist?

Tags: c#, ravendb

how do I check programmatically if my Raven Db (http://ravendb.net/) called "Test" exist?

Best regards

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. `EnsureDatabaseExists` is an extension method on `IDatabaseCommands` defined in the `Raven.Client.Extensions` namespace.

To make it work you need to add a using statement for this namespace.

```
 using Raven.Client;
 using Raven.Client.Extensions;

 using (DocumentStore store = new DocumentStore()
 {
     Url = "http://localhost:8080/" ;
 })
 {
     store.Initialize();
    store.DatabaseCommands.EnsureDatabaseExists("SomeDatabase");
}
```

2. This is an extensions method I use for that:

   ```
   public static bool DatabaseExists(this IDocumentStore documentStore, 
   string databaseName) 
   { 
     var headers = documentStore.DatabaseCommands.Head("Raven/Databases/" + databaseName); 
     return headers != null; 
   }
   ```

Easily called:

```
bool exists = documentStore.DatabaseExists("foo");
```

*This works when your documentStore is pointed at raven's default 
system database.  If you set a DefaultDatabase on the document store, 
I don't believe it would work properly.*

Comment: Hi all. In version 4.0, RavenDb has removed DatabaseCommands. How would this be implemented?

Comment: You can use `GetDatabaseRecordOperation`
`var result = store.Maintenance.Server.Send(new GetDatabaseRecordOperation(DatabaseName))` if the result is null the database is not exists